# Vertical spacing in equation after splitting

Tags: spacing, split, vertical

I need to reduce the vertical spacing after a formula. After I split the formula, the vertical space increased.

[image]

Code:

```
Objective Function
\setlength\belowdisplayskip{10pt plus 1pt minus 10pt}
\setcounter{equation}{0}
\begin{align}
\begin{split}
\text{minimize} \qquad & \space F1:\Bigg [\sum_{t\in T} \left(UU_t + OU_t \right)\Bigg] + \\
  &\qquad F2: \Bigg[\sum_{p\in P} w^i_p X_p + \sum_{k} \frac{1}{k} \left( \sum_{p\in p} \sum_{t\in T} w^e_p Y_{pt} + \sum_{p\in p} \sum_{t\in T} w^t_p \eta_{pt}\ + \right. \\  
& \qquad \left.  \sum_{p\in p} \sum_{t\in T} w^u_p \Omega_{pt}\ + \sum_{p\in p} \sum_{t\in T} w^q_p \Delta_{pt}\ \right) \Bigg]
\end{split}
\end{align}
```

Comment: I don't get the output as shown in your picture. Can you complete your code by adding in the relevant document class and packages?

Answer (score 1):

I would like to suggest that you rewrite the entire expression along the following lines:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
Objective Function $F=F_1+F_2$, where 
\begin{align}
F_1 &= \sum_{t\in T} (UU_t + OU_t)\\
\shortintertext{and}
F_2 &= \sum_{p\in P} w^i_p X_p + \sum_{k} 
       \frac{1}{k} \biggl(\,\sum_{p\in p} \sum_{t\in T} w^e_p Y_{pt} + \sum_{p\in p} \sum_{t\in T} w^t_p \eta_{pt} \notag\\  
& \qquad +\sum_{p\in p} \sum_{t\in T} w^u_p \Omega_{pt}\ + \sum_{p\in p} \sum_{t\in T} w^q_p \Delta_{pt} \biggr)
\end{align} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Dear @AnaBatista, instead say "thank you" you should vote for answer (by clicking the upper pen at top left side of answer, as I do just now) and if it solve your problem accept it (by clicking on check mark below pens) :).

Comment: @Zarko - I couldn't have said it better. :-)